# Can I paste juypter notebook source code directly into a notebook page?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Can I paste juypter notebook source code directly into a notebook page?

I mean if i code a .ipynb file open in a text editor can I just copy and paste it into a running notebook? Or is that just madness?

Thanks,

Comment: You can do that and it will not change anything to the ongoing running process. But, why would you want to do that? Any particular reason?

Comment: I realised you can just upload an .ipynb file I just wanted to shortcut the process as I had a file open and wanted to interrogate it line by line as a notebook. When you say you can copy paste raw code though, is there a source code view button in notebooks or colabs?